# Large round (20 or 24 inch) LED or OLED display?

Tags: lcd, oled

Is their any such thing as a 20 or 24 inch round LED or OLED display? I've searched and searched to no avail and I am wondering is that even possible?

Answer (score 2):

It's probably "possible", but very expensive per unit and carrying an enormous minimum order cost and/or very high NRE costs.

Suggest you mask off a rectangular LCD or plasma display with a round bezel. A 42" to 50" panel would be required for 20" to 24" diameter. Such panels are mass produced for televisions and are relatively cheap.

Comment: Or see if you can start off with something with an aspect ratio close to 1:1.